# How can I access the Strings list from [0 to 9] outside for loop?

Tags: java, string, list, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write a code that allows me to access String msgbody and place it in an email. However, using the following code only the final String shows up outside the for loop. I searched many times for an answer, and am a bit new to Java.

```
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    String msgbody = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
            //urls.get(i); unecessary
            // String msgbody0; - Used to attempt msgbody0 = url.get(i); then msgbody += msgbody0; but only prints first url
            int sum = i + 1;
            for (j = 1; j < 2 ; j++)
            {
                msgbody = urls.get(i);

                //urls.add(msgbody); not needed
                System.out.print("("+ sum +")" +"");
                System.out.println(msgbody); 
            }
            if(i==9){
                break;
            }
        } // Inside the for loop everything prints properly.

       System.out.println(msgbody); // How can i replicate it here?(Outside for loop)
```

Edit:
THIS worked:
(Initially -The following only shows the first link repeatedly:)
I changed from Java to Java EE and it worked? What was i missing?

```
    msgbody += urls.get(i);
```

I can make it work without the for loop, but its sloppy.

Comment: I need urls from urls.get(0) to urls.get(9)

Comment: from where `urls` having values? its just initialized? values are not assigned in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change `msgbody = urls.get(i);` to `msgbody += urls.get(i);` (otherwise you're completely replacing the `msgbody` with each iteration). Also, I would prefer a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), the [diamond operator `<>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) and a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Like,

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String url : urls) {
    sb.append(urls.get(url));
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the reply, I will read more about the StringBuilder and try this method. I'll let you know if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

only the minor change is that you are replacing msgbody rather than to concatenate it.

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    String msgbody = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
            //urls.get(i); unecessary
            // String msgbody0; - Used to attempt msgbody0 = url.get(i); then msgbody += msgbody0; but only prints first url
            int sum = i + 1;
            for (j = 1; j < 2 ; j++)
            {
                msgbody += urls.get(i);

                urls.add(msgbody);
                System.out.print("("+ sum +")" +"");
                System.out.println(msgbody); 
            }
            if(i==9){
                break;
            }
        } // Inside the for loop everything prints properly.

       System.out.println(msgbody);
```

Comment: Both answers are correct. He provided an alternative so I gave him the check. Thank you for the reply.